# additionalUnattendContent content being rejected by Azure Virtual Machines REST API

Tags: xml, api, rest, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm writing an interface between a cloud orchestration tool and Azure REST API (Resource Manager) but I'm running into an issue testing the Windows additionalUnattendContent functionality to get Unattend.xml injections working.

Why is the code below not being accepted by the API service? The documentation shows an example of additionalUnattendContent as a KV pair object, but I found (by searching through the actual ARM spec) that it's actually a list of objects. It also specifies that the content portion should be base64 encoded and no larger than 4KiB in size and to include the root element for the features or setting (not entirely sure what this means). I've encoded what I think is a valid XML component, but it throws an error (code and error noted below).  I've tried this using both API version 2016-03-30 and 2015-05-01-preview with the same results.

This is the osProfile excerpt from my request to the API service.

```
"osProfile": {
  "adminUsername": "winuxadmin",
  "computername": "vm331d4bwx",
  "windowsConfiguration": {
    "additionalUnattendContent": [{
      "content": "PFN5bmNocm9ub3VzQ29tbWFuZCB3Y206YWN0aW9uPSJhZGQiPjxDb21tYW5kTGluZT4lU3lzdGVtUm9vdCVcc3lzdGVtMzJcbmV0c2ggYWR2ZmlyZXdhbGwgYWRkIHJ1bGUgbmFtZT0iV2luUk0gSFRUUCA1OTg1IiBwcm90b2NvbD0iVENQIiBkaXI9ImluIiBsb2NhbHBvcnQ9IjU5ODUiIGFjdGlvbj0iYWxsb3ciPC9Db21tYW5kTGluZT48T3JkZXI+MTwvT3JkZXI+PERlc2NyaXB0aW9uPk9wZW4gV2luUk0gSFRUUCBwb3J0PC9EZXNjcmlwdGlvbj48L1N5bmNocm9ub3VzQ29tbWFuZD4=",
      "componentName": "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup",
      "settingName": "FirstLogonCommands",
      "passName": "oobeSystem"
    }],
    "winRM": {
      "listeners": [{
        "protocol": "http",
        "certificateUrl": null
      }]
    },
    "provisionVMAgent": true
  },
  "adminPassword": "MyW1nP@ssw0rd"
},
```

The base64 XML additionalUnattendContent[0].content decodes to this (***note***: I have also done the same test but with the content XML wrapping in the root setting node - `<FirstLogonCommands>...</FirstLogonCommands>` - but the result is the same). The actual Windows command here isn't really important and more likely would need to be a WinRM command to allow unencrypted connections, but the issue isn't really command-related -

```
<SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
  <CommandLine>%SystemRoot%\system32\netsh advfirewall add rule name="WinRM HTTP 5985" protocol="TCP" dir="in" localport="5985" action="allow"</CommandLine>
  <Order>1</Order>
  <Description>Enable QuickEdit mode</Description>
</SynchronousCommand>
```

Once I realized that the official docs were wrong about the format of additionalUnattendContent (it should be a list of objects and not just an object), I was able to get to the following error from the API service -

```
statusCode:BadRequest serviceRequestId:<req-id> statusMessage:
{
  "error": 
  {
    "code": "InvalidParameter",
    "target": "windowsConfiguration.additionalUnattendContent.content",
    "message": "The value of parameter windowsConfiguration.additionalUnattendContent.content is invalid."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience has been:

- it is an array
- it should not be base64 encoded
- attributes with colons cause strange errors (e.g. wcm:action=...)

Here is a working example:

```
"additionalUnattendContent": [
  {
    "passName": "oobesystem",
    "componentName": "Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup",
    "settingName": "FirstLogonCommands",
    "content": "<FirstLogonCommands><SynchronousCommand><CommandLine>shutdown /r /t 0 /c \"initial reboot\"</CommandLine><Description>reboot</Description><Order>1</Order></SynchronousCommand></FirstLogonCommands>"
  }
]
```

Here is a discussion on the topic:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/issues/1407

Comment: +1 Q&A Thank you for the sign posts! Had to struggle with the second issue too! I wonder if actually including the xmlns namespace info (xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State") could also fix the issue? Didn't get to try it yet though.